# translating ejs injection to .dot engine way

Tags: ejs, template-engine, dot.js

Hey guy i'm having trouble to get this work, any help would be much apreciated

I usually use this in my ejs engine template

```
<%= blog.created_at.getFullYear() %>
<%= blog.short_name.replace(new RegExp(" ", "g"), "-") %>
<%= blog.content.match(/<img[^>]+src="([^">]+)/)[1] %>
```

but I have trouble making this work in .dot engine. I  know my problem are javascript function, regex and match I'm using. meaning **bold** part, is not correct here ( **getFullYear()** , **replace(new RegExp(" ", "g"), "-")** , **match(/]+src="([^">]+)/)[1]** )

```
{%= blog.created_at.getFullYear() %}
{%= blog.short_name.replace(new RegExp(" ", "g"), "-") %}
{%= blog.content.match(/<img[^>]+src="([^">]+)/)[1] %}
```

what should be use instead in those cases?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

after some test I realized:

first : I'm doing this wrong. I'm trying to gen and img's src from a html string (that's what the regex does ) but does it really need to be that way?? ...of course NO. So the best thing in my case is do this on the route before render using underscore.

```
  _.map(array, function(object,key){
       return _.extend(object, {image: img_sources || 'image'}); 
    });
```

second: the problem here resides in chars like "(double quotes), [ ] 
(squarebrackes) , and probably some other . I'have achieved a way to replace all those chars and still the regex work. Use the better the solution above.